# How to access to an object data php cakephp 3.1

Tags: php, cakephp

this is a cakephp 3.1 query result, I whant to access directly to $data->items but I get an error saying the key item is not found and I don't whant to use the funtcion toArray() because if I do that it will return only the 'items' => ... and I lost all 'query' => ... informations.
can you help me with the right syntaxe to get $data->items or $data->{'items'} ...
.

```
$data = object(Cake\ORM\ResultSet) {

    'query' => object(Cake\ORM\Query) {

        '(help)' => 'This is a Query object, to get the results execute or iterate it.',
        'sql' => 'SELECT Posts_types.id AS `Posts_types__id`, Posts_types.name AS `Posts_types__name` FROM posts_types Posts_types ORDER BY id ASC',
        'params' => [],
        'defaultTypes' => [
            'Posts_types.id' => 'integer',
            'id' => 'integer',
            'Posts_types.name' => 'string',
            'name' => 'string'
        ],
        'decorators' => (int) 0,
        'executed' => true,
        'hydrate' => true,
        'buffered' => true,
        'formatters' => (int) 0,
        'mapReducers' => (int) 0,
        'contain' => [],
        'matching' => [],
        'extraOptions' => [],
        'repository' => object(Cake\ORM\Table) {

            'registryAlias' => 'Posts_types',
            'table' => 'posts_types',
            'alias' => 'Posts_types',
            'entityClass' => '\Cake\ORM\Entity',
            'associations' => [],
            'behaviors' => [],
            'defaultConnection' => 'default',
            'connectionName' => 'default'

        }

    },
    'items' => [
        (int) 0 => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

            'id' => (int) 1,
            'name' => 'Descriptif de la formation',
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Posts_types'

        },
        (int) 1 => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

            'id' => (int) 2,
            'name' => 'Cours',
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Posts_types'

        },
        (int) 2 => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

            'id' => (int) 3,
            'name' => 'Evénements',
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Posts_types'

        }
    ]

}
```

Comment: Would be useful/helpful to know what you are currently doing and what problem you are trying to solve - you can just do `foreach($resultSet as $row)` for example. Please add your actual problem to the question.

Comment: thak you for your answer. as you know sometimes you need to access to a specific information in the data query, for example if I whant to get the $data->query what should I do? It returns an error event if I whrite $data->{'query'}

Comment: Comments are not answers - they are normally used to ask you to **edit the question with more information**.

Answer (score 6):

### There is no items property

The items key in the question is the result of calling `toArray`, which *is* the direct answer to what you've asked.

As may be obvious looking at the public methods for [the result set class](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.1.0/src/ORM/ResultSet.php), and [the collection trait](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.1.0/src/Collection/CollectionTrait.php) which it uses, none of the properties of a result set are intended to be directly accessed.

Here's a simple example demonstrating how to use result sets:

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

$resultSet = TableRegistry::get('Posts');

// Iterate it
foreach($resultSet as $postObject) {
    echo $postObject->title;
}

// Obtain data as an array
$arrayofPostObjects = $resultSet->toArray();

echo get_class($resultSet); // It is still a result set
```

Note that calling methods on a resultSet does not change what it is - it is *still* a result set, there is no loss of information. There's a misunderstanding in the question but because it's not clear what you're doing it's not clear what that misunderstanding is.

### What about getting the query?

In comments you've asked:

> if I want to get $data->query what should I do?

This is something your application should never do, as a developer you'd normally want to do that only as part of debugging. Most classes implement [__debugInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.debuginfo) - which is where the two keys "query" and "items" come from when [debug/var_dumping a result set object](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.1.0/src/ORM/ResultSet.php#L622-L628):

```
/**
 * Returns an array that can be used to describe the internal state of this
 * object.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function __debugInfo()
{
    return [
        'query' => $this->_query,
        'items' => $this->toArray(),
    ];
}
```

So to get the query, the only thing you need to do is debug/var_dump the object. As previously mentioned this also shows that "items" is simply the result of calling `toArray`.

Note that to log all queries configure [query logging](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#database-query-logging), obviously all developers should be using [Debug Kit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) in development.

Answer (score 1):

By default queries and result sets will return Entities objects. You can retrieve basic arrays by disabling hydration:

add this to your query
->hydrate(false)